# exporting some of data in a text file to a CSV file, while text file has different types of delimiters

Tags: python, csv, text

```
TT1  4444 | Drowsy | 9 19   bit drowsy
TT2  45888 | Blurred see - hazy | 29 50 little seeing vision
TT4  45933 | Excessive upper pain  | 62 78  pain problems
```

I want export part of the information to a excel sheet or CSV file. my expected CSV file is like this:

```
Column 1    Column 2                      column 3
4444        Drowsy                        bit drowsy 
45888       Blurred see - hazy            little seeing vision
45933       Excessive upper pain          pain problems
```

As you see, I do not need information in first, fourth, and fifth column of a text file.

**UPDATE FOR THE QUESTION:**
structure of information in some of the rows is as follows:

```
TT6 112397013 | ari | or 76948002|pain| 22 345  agony
```

The expected output is as follows:

```
Column 1    Column 2                      column 3
112397013     air                          agony
76948002      pain                         agony
```

Second Update for the Question: there is another exception in the text file:

```
TT9 CONCEPT_LESS 336 344    mobility
```

I just want the output of this line to be like this:

```
CONCEPT_LESS   mobility
```

Any suggestion ? Thanks !

Comment: how is your data stored in python?

Comment: @depperm, are you asking about my previous question ? If yes,  Wednesday, I will have access to the data, and I will  test the solution. Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since input text file don't have one specific type of delimiter either pipe or space or comma, we need to read file as string.

To extract the required information, regex is used.

**csv module** is used to create and write data to csv.

Please [check here](https://pymotw.com/2/csv/) for more info on csv module.

**Content of xyz.txt** :

```
TT1  4444 | Drowsy | 9 19   bit drowsy
TT2  45888 | Blurred see - hazy | 29 50 little seeing vision
TT4  45933 | Excessive upper pain  | 62 78  pain problems
TT6 112397013 | air | or 76948002|pain| 22 345  agony
TT9 CONCEPT_LESS 336 344    mobility
```

**Code (Comments inline):**

```
import re
import csv


def extract_data(val):
    tmp1,tmp2,tmp3 = val[0],val[1],val[2]
    tmp1 = re.findall(r'.*\s+(\w+)',tmp1.strip())[0]
    tmp2 = tmp2.strip()
    tmp3 = re.findall(r'\s+(\D+)',tmp3.strip())[0]
    return (tmp1,tmp2,tmp3)

#Open CSV file for wrting data
csv_fh = open("demo.csv", 'w')
writer = csv.writer(csv_fh)
#Write Header to csv file
writer.writerow( ('Column 1', 'Column 2', 'Column 3') )

#Start reading text file line by line
with open("xyz.txt","r") as fh:
    for line in fh.readlines():
        #Check or in line
        if "or" in line:
            val_list = line.split('|')
            val1 = val_list[:2]
            val2 = val_list[2:]
            val1.append(val2[-1])
            for v in [val1,val2]:
                l = extract_data(v)
                writer.writerow( l )
        elif '|' in line and 'or' not in line:
            #Split on basis of pipe(|)
            val = line.split('|')
            l = extract_data(val)
            writer.writerow( l )
        elif '|' not in line:
            val = line.split()
            data = [val[1],val[4],'']
            writer.writerow( data )
        else:
            pass

#Close CSV file
csv_fh.close()
```

**Content of demo.csv :**

```
Column 1,Column 2,Column 3
4444,Drowsy,bit drowsy
45888,Blurred see - hazy,little seeing vision
45933,Excessive upper pain,pain problems
112397013,air,agony
76948002,pain,agony
CONCEPT_LESS,mobility,
```

Comment: thank you very much !, there are two errors in the code: for the lines: writer.writerow( ('Column 1', 'Column 2', 'Column 3') )  and  writer.writerow( [tmp1,tmp2,tmp3] ), it says "TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'"

Comment: @Mary - Please check the updated code. I have changed it so that it will work for your update in question also.

Comment: @Mary - I think you are using Python 3. That's why you are getting error (In comment 2). Only change required is  csv_fh = open("demo.csv", 'wb') to csv_fh = open("demo.csv", 'w'). I have changed this in my updated code.

Comment: perfect code. It works very well. Would you please check my second second update ?

Comment: @Mary - Updated the code. Please check it.

Comment: would you please answer this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39938210/regular-expression-to-replace-some-dots-with-commas-in-customers-comments

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you can read in the data as a list of strings. The code parses them using regular expressions (re) to the desired output which you can then write out to a csv file:

```
import re

#read lines from file using:
#lines = my_file.readlines()
lines = ["TT1  4444 | Drowsy | 9 19   bit drowsy",
         "TT2  45888 | Blurred see - hazy | 29 50 little seeing vision",
         "TT4  45933 | Excessive upper pain  | 62 78  pain problems"]

#Looks for TT some whitespace then numbers until another whitespace and vertical bar
tt_num_pattern = "TT.*\s([0-9].*?)\s"

#Only looks for letters after a space
describe_pattern = "\s(\D.*)"

#Format the output lines
out_lines = []
for line in lines:
    split_line = line.split("|")
    tt_num = re.findall(tt_num_pattern,split_line[0])[0]

    state = split_line[1].strip() #Just trim edges of whitespace
    describe = re.findall(describe_pattern,split_line[2])[0]
    describe = describe.strip()

    out_line = tt_num+","+state+","+describe
    out_lines.append(out_line)

#Print them out (would normally want to write to file after header line)
for out_line in out_lines:
    print out_line
```

output:

```
4444,Drowsy,bit drowsy
45888,Blurred see - hazy,little seeing vision
45933,Excessive upper pain,pain problems
```

Glad this helped. Here is the update you asked for. Honestly it's not very good (flexible) code but it works:

```
import re

#read lines from file using:
#lines = my_file.readlines()
lines = ["TT1  4444 | Drowsy | 9 19   bit drowsy",
         "TT2  45888 | Blurred see - hazy | 29 50 little seeing vision",
         "TT4  45933 | Excessive upper pain  | 62 78  pain problems",
         "TT6 112397013 | air | or 76948002|pain| 22 345  agony"]

#Looks for TT some whitespace then numbers until another whitespace and vertical bar
tt_num_pattern = "TT.*\s([0-9].*?)\s"

#Only looks for letters after a space
describe_pattern = "\s(\D.*)"

#Format the output lines
out_lines = []
for line in lines:

    split_line = line.split("|")

    #If there is an 'or'
    if len(split_line) == 5:
        tt_num = split_line[2].replace("or","").strip()
        state = split_line[3].strip()
        describe = re.findall(describe_pattern,split_line[4])[0].strip()
        out_line = tt_num+","+state+","+describe
        out_lines.append(out_line)

        tt_num = re.findall(tt_num_pattern,split_line[0])[0]
        state = split_line[1].strip()
        out_line = tt_num+","+state+","+describe
        out_lines.append(out_line)


    #If there is no 'or'
    elif len(split_line) == 3:
        tt_num = re.findall(tt_num_pattern,split_line[0])[0]

        state = split_line[1].strip() #Just trim edges of whitespace
        describe = re.findall(describe_pattern,split_line[2])[0]
        describe = describe.strip()

        out_line = tt_num+","+state+","+describe
        out_lines.append(out_line)

#Print them out (would normally want to write to file after header line)
for out_line in out_lines:
    print out_line
```

updated output:

```
4444,Drowsy,bit drowsy
45888,Blurred see - hazy,little seeing vision
45933,Excessive upper pain,pain problems
76948002,pain,agony
112397013,air,agony
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, Would you please check  the updated part of my question ?

Comment: I highly appreciate your time. There is another exception in the file. Would you please check it again ?

Comment: Hi @Mary, it looks like Dinesh has you covered :)

Comment: would you please answer this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39938210/regular-expression-to-replace-some-dots-with-commas-in-customers-comments